# Replication of mysql table at runtime

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my MySQL for which I want to create a replica in some other database on the same MySQL instance with a different table name.

For eg 
I have two database X and Y.

X contains a table by the name of A. Direct insertions takes place in this table only.

Y database will contain a table by the name of B which will contain the same data as of A.

MySQL version - 5.6

I have explored the options for copy of data. But this will not happen at runtime. I want a structure something like as soon as an insertion or updation takes place in table A, same data gets copied/updated to table B.

I also explored the option for the master-slave concept, in which it provides the copy to some other server. However, for this, a separate DB is needed but I want to be in the same DB instance.

I have no idea as to such a feature exists or not, or do I need to create such thing manually via code, or I have missed something in the above two ways which they can be modified and get the required result.

Can anyone please guide/help me with this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can 'Triggers' help?

Comment: I think these can help. I'll explore this section too.

Comment: Triggers are a set of queries which are triggered upon some event on the table, *Create, Update, Delete, etc...* Check [MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html) for more details